# how to save iptables changes in fedora 22

Tags: fedora, iptables

After every restart the changes I make to iptables are lost. I know now that I have to save the changes after making them, but every way of saving I tried so far doesn't work.

I tried the following :

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save (command not found)
/usr/libexec/iptables.init save (command not found)
/sbin/service iptables save (the service supports only basic lsb actions)
```

I'm just a basic *nix user, so most of my knowledge is based on uncle Google and I cannot find more solutions at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm on Fedora 22 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fedora uses firewalld in recent versions, you need to do it with firewalld commands. Take a look [here](https://serverfault.com/a/674887/330968)

If you insist to use iptables, you need to install iptables in order to use `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` commands using `dnf install iptables` .